# Boolean Algebra - Demorgan Laws

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am given the problem:

!((!A * B) * !((!B + C) * (!C * !D)))

where ! = NOT, * = AND, and + = OR and I tried simplifying it using only Demorgan Laws (no absorption) and I got:

(A + !B) + ((!B + C) + (C + D))

and I was just wondering if it was correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Ok, thanks.

Comment: They are not equivalent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to do the DeMorgan's law portion of the simplification, (using your notation)

!((!A * B) * !((!B + C) * (!C * !D)))
 <==> !(!A*B) + !!((!B + C) * (!C * !D)) (first round of DeMorgan's law usage)
 <==> (A + !B) + !!((!B + C) * (!C * !D)) (second round of DeMorgan's law usage)

Now, if we want to finish simplifying,

(A + !B) + !!((!B + C) * (!C * !D))
 <==> A + !B + (!B + C) * (!C * !D)   (simplifying the !!)
 <==> A + !B + (!B * !C * !D) + (!C * C * !D)    (distribution)
 <==> A + !B + (!B * !C * !D) + 0    (!C * C * !D is equivalent to 0)
 <==> A + !B + (!B * !C * !D) 
 <==> A + !B   (using the unavailable absorption law you mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

If we let $\overline{A}$ signify "$\text{not}\ A$", then I get the following

$$\phantom{\iff\quad} !((!A * B) * !((!B + C) * (!C * !D)))$$
$$\iff\quad \overline{(\overline{A} * B) * \overline{(\overline{B} + C) * (\overline{C} * \overline{D}))}}$$
$$\iff\quad \overline{(\overline{A} * B)} + (\overline{B} + C) * (\overline{C} * \overline{D}))$$
$$\iff\quad (A + \overline{B}) + (\overline{B} + C) * (\overline{C} * \overline{D}))$$
$$\iff\quad (A * !B) + ((!B + C) * (!C * !D))$$

This is slightly different from the answer you got.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to account for the outside ! on my last term, it should have been !(C + D) which would have given me (!C * !D) (Which is what you got)